# Why can't we use sum of absolute residuals instead of R squared method in Linear regression

Tags: regression, r-squared

I am fairly new to statistics, so can somebody explain to me the given question in simple terminology. I read almost all answers on stack exchange but all I can say is they are too technical for me. A basic idea regarding the problem will be very helpful.

edit : P.S I'm using the R squared method for finding the best fit line for the data,I mean using absolute value instead of squaring to make the misses positive

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Use where? To evaluate model? You can.

Comment: Do you mean using absolute value instead of squaring to make the “misses” all positive?

Comment: If you mean "why can't we use least absolute deviations instead of least squares to obtain a regression line" ... you can. Such regression ($L_1$ regression, least absolute values regression) is discussed in numerous questions and answers here. Numerous other methods of finding regression lines (I'd think at least 7 or 8, probably more; I think I've discussed more than five others myself) are discussed in other questions. Many more approaches still have been used and many more again could be.

Comment: You can. It is a particular case of quantile regression where the quantile is $0.50$ (the median). The classical interpretation is that you then are estimating the conditional median instead of the conditional mean given by least squares, though it may turn out to give better estimates of conditional means than least squares does. Also notable is that, much as minimizing square loss is equivalent to maximum likelihood estimation when the error term is Gaussian, minimizing absolute loss is equivalent to maximum likelihood estimation when the error is Laplace-distributed.

Comment: This [site search for quantile regression answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=quantile+regression+median+score%3A5+is%3Aanswer) ought to help.